# how to combine keras loss with other intermediate output loss using model.add_loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to reproduce [COSTA/VAE](https://github.com/costapt/adversarial_retinal_synthesis) code to make it run on tf2.x and Keras 2.x rather than 1.x.
however, I am facing problem in combining Keras loss (which are tensors) with some intermediate layer outputs (which are KerasTensors).

here is the code with custom loss function

```
def gan_loss(y_true, y_pred,a,ap,b,bp):
      y_true_flat = K.batch_flatten(y_true)
      y_pred_flat = K.batch_flatten(y_pred)
      # # Adversarial Loss
      L_adv = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true_flat, y_pred_flat)

      # A to A loss
      a_flat = K.batch_flatten(a)
      ap_flat = K.batch_flatten(ap)
      if is_a_binary:
          L_atoa = losses.binary_crossentropy(a_flat, ap_flat)
      else:
          L_atoa = K.mean(K.abs(a_flat - ap_flat))

      # A to B loss
      b_flat = K.batch_flatten(b)
      bp_flat = K.batch_flatten(bp)
      if is_b_binary:
          L_atob = losses.binary_crossentropy(b_flat, bp_flat)
      else:
          L_atob = K.mean(K.abs(b_flat - bp_flat))

      L_code = losses.binary_crossentropy(np.asarray(1).astype('float32').reshape((-1, 1)), code_d(z))

      return L_adv + beta*L_atoa + alpha*L_atob + L_code
      


a = Input(shape=(1, 512, 512),name='a')
b = Input(shape=(3, 512, 512),name='b')    

# A -> A'  converting groundtruth (A) to noise (z) then generate (A') using VAE
encoder = vae.get_layer('vae_encoder')
decoder = vae.get_layer('vae_decoder')
z = encoder(a)
ap = decoder(z)      # ap is the (A') which is short form of A prediction(ap)

# A' -> B'   convert A' to synthesized image (B') via image-to-image translation 
bp = atob(ap)  
  
# Discriminator receives the two generated images
d_in = concatenate([ap, bp], axis=1)
output= d(d_in)
input= [a,b]
gan = Model(input , output)

gan.add_loss(gan_loss(y_true,y_pred,a,ap,b,bp))      <------ HERE IS THE PROBLEM
gan.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=None)
```

Note: the code works fine if i removed either `y_true,y_pred` or `a,ap,b,bp` from the calculation of loss function, but it throws an error if i used them together in the calculation of loss function

**the Question: What shall i send for y_true and y_pred as they are implicitly send if we follow the standard form of loss calculation like `gan.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=gan_loss)`**

here is the full error report

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-11-208ba3569274> in <module>()
----> 1 train(models, it_train, it_val, params)

4 frames
<ipython-input-9-96f21ec5c376> in train(models, it_train, it_val, 
params)
357 
358         for b in range(batches_per_epoch):
--> 359             train_iteration(models, generators, losses, 
params)
360 
361         # Evaluate how the models is doing on the validation set.

<ipython-input-9-96f21ec5c376> in train_iteration(models, generators, 
losses, params)
282     print(p2p2p_gen)
283 
--> 284     p2p2phist = train_generator(p2p2p, p2p2p_gen, 
batch_size=params.batch_size)
285     print()
286     print('p2p2phist.history')
 
<ipython-input-9-96f21ec5c376> in train_generator(gan, it, 
batch_size)
55     """Train the generator network."""
56     #return gan.fit_generator(it, nb_epoch=1, 
samples_per_epoch=batch_size, verbose=False)
---> 57     return gan.fit(it, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=batch_size, 
verbose=False)#,initial_epoch=1)
58 
59 def discriminator_generator(it, g, dout_size=(16, 16)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py 
in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
68     finally:
69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149               raise

TypeError: in user code:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 240, in __call__
total_loss_metric_value, sample_weight=batch_dim)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 
178, in update_state_fn
return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 
456, in update_state  **
sample_weight, values)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 255, in __array__
f'You are passing {self}, an intermediate Keras symbolic 
input/output, '

TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), 
dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', 
description="created by layer 'tf.cast_5'"), an intermediate Keras 
symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering 
custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, 
or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF 
API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or 
`tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic 
Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting 
the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer 
on this symbolic input/output.
```

Thanks for bearing this with me.

Comment: Your code does not include your imports. Some answers on StackOverflow tell you to import from tensorflow.keras instead of just keras.

One option is to add the layer outputs as separate model outputs. A Functional Model can have multiple outputs. You then ignore them for prediction, but use them for calculating loss.

It would be helpful to post your entire source as a Colab notebook.

Comment: @ALIQSAEED could u provide vae, atob, d and opt ?

Comment: Kindly find the full code on Colab on the following link   https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JqzdcMZre4QIHJGW17WQ8GQss8ipAYRd?usp=sharing @MarcoCerliani

Comment: @JackParsons, all imports already exist in the main code and it is working properly on keras 1.x and tf 1.x, but i didn't include them in the post just included the part that makes the problem. Anyway, you may find the full code on Colab on the following link please  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JqzdcMZre4QIHJGW17WQ8GQss8ipAYRd?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There have been some complex changes "under the hood" for Tensorflow 2.x/Keras 2.x. My advice is to add this as the first line:

```
!pip uninstall -y keras
```

Then, change all imports of keras to tensorflow.keras. By mixing the 'keras' and 'tensorflow' packages, you could be mixing up types and functions invisibly.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, however this answer didn't solve the problem.. same error mesg is appearing. i guess the correct answer is to use model,add_loss() but i don't know how to explicitly pass y_true and y_pred which are implicitly sent while calling the loss fun through model.comple(). any expert may help with this issue please?